# min/max with orm relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find the min/max of a collection off a foreign key. I know that you can do `session.query` with `func.min` and `func.max`, but is there a way that lets me use the standard ORM relationship stuff?

For example with a blog, if I wanted to find the biggest "number comment" for a given post given the schema below, is it possible to do something like `Post.query.get(0).number_comments.max()`?

```
class Post(base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  number_comments = relationship("NumberComment")

class NumberComment(base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  num = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

As in case of using raw SQL, you need to join those tables in your query:

```
# This class lacks a foreign key in your example.
class NumberComment(base):
    # ...
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Post.id), nullable=False)
    # ...

session.query(func.max(NumberComment.num)).join(Post).\
    filter(Post.id == 1).scalar()
```

There's no other way to do this, at least not like you wanted. There's a reason why SQLAlchemy is called like that and not ORMSorcery ;-)

My advice would be to think in terms of SQL when trying to come up with a query, this will help you a lot.